# Hard disk drivers for Windows Server 2008 R2 installer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hardware-raid

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on my server that uses RAID 1 on 2 146GB SCSI drives. However, when I get to the partition selection screen, nothing displays. I'm guessing this is because the installer doesn't know how to interface with the RAID array without the correct driver, but I do not know where I can get a driver for the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out what disk controller you have - open it up and look, look at the delivery note or on the manufacturer's website (you'll probably get the driver from there anyway).

Let us know more detail about the server and we'll be able to help more.